# Spotfire Consecutive Count

Tags: spotfire

I am new to Spotfire so I hope that I ask this question correctly.

My table contains `Corp_ID`, `Date` and `Flagged` columns. The flagged column is either "1" or "0" based on if that `Corp_ID` had production on that date.

I need a custom expression that will return "0" if the flagged column is "0", BUT if the flagged column is "1" then I need it to return how many **consecutive** "1"s are in that string for that `Corp_ID`.

```
Corp_ID   Date         Flagged      New Column
101       1/1/2016     1            1
101       1/2/2016     0            0
101       1/3/2016     1            4
101       1/4/2016     1            4
101       1/5/2016     1            4
101       1/6/2016     1            4
101       1/7/2016     0            0
101       1/8/2016     0            0
101       1/9/2016     1            2
101       1/10/2016    1            2
102       1/2/2016     1            3
102       1/3/2016     1            3
102       1/4/2016     1            3
102       1/5/2016     0            0
102       1/6/2016     0            0
102       1/7/2016     0            0
102       1/8/2016     1            4
102       1/9/2016     1            4
102       1/10/2016    1            4
102       1/11/2016    1            4
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!
KC

Comment: Can you do this in the data pull?  If this is coming from some form of SQL, it would probably be easier to do there rather than in Spotfire.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier to implement as part of the query you’re using to return the data, but if you have to do it in spotfire, I suggest this.

1-  Create a hierarchy column containing  [Corp_ID] and [Date] (Named ‘DateHr’)

2-  Add a calculated column named ‘Concat Flags’ which concatenates all the previous flag values: Concatenate([Flagged]) OVER (Intersect(Parent([Hierarchy.DateHr]),allPrevious([Hierarchy.DateHr])))

3-  Add a calculated column which will return the number of 0’s in the Concat Flags field (Named ‘# of 0s’): Len([Concat Flags]) - Len(Substitute([Concat Flags],"0",""))

4-  Add a hierarchy column containing  [Corp_ID] and [# of 0s] (Named ‘CorpHr’)

5-  Add a calculated column to return your desired value: case  when [Flagged]=1 then Sum([Flagged]) OVER (Intersect([Hierarchy.CorpHr])) else 0 end

Note: the above assumes you are working in Spotfire version 7.5. The syntax for using hierarchies in calculated columns differs slightly in earlier versions).

Comment: thank you, I think this would be my solution but I have 7.0 and when i try to use this it takes a long time to run. Any ideas on how to do this in SQL before the data is surfaced in spotfire?